# Hide scrollbars for responsive design view in Firefox without affecting mobile IE10?

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

The Responsive Design View in Firefox includes a vertical scrollbar within the tested width, which makes previewing a site compared to a real mobile device without scrollbars slightly uncomfortable. So I added

```
html{ overflow-y: hidden; }
```

to my CSS. While this works perfectly for desktop testing, all iOS devices I checked and most of the Android devices too, it completely screws up the site in IE10 on Windows Phone 8: The page starts jumping like crazy when you use navigations and forms, sometimes it even shows a blank screen that goes away if you scroll slightly.

It took me several days to figure out this issue as I am working on a quite complex site, so just to let everyone know who has similar problems.

How do you prevent this when using the Responsive Design View in Firefox?

Meanwhile I have switched to a responsive preview bookmarklet (http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/) that does not show the scrollbar anyway. Mozilla seems to address this with "mobile scrollbars" in upcoming version 22 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGCbIMH3gMM).

Comment: maybe you could temporaly add a css-class with html,body{max-width:100%;overflow-y:hidden} for your case

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, John. IE10 mobile freaks out with this as well, so you really have to add it temporarily for desktop testing, maybe with some browser sniffing JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, writing a style specifically for mozilla will solve this issue.

```
eg: @-moz-document url-prefix() 
    {
        html{ overflow-y: hidden; }
    }
```

Place the code specifically for mozilla towards the bottom of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox shows scrollbars according to the operating system preferences. If you're on Mac OSX Mountain Lion (10.8), open *System Preferences > General* and choose to *Show scroll bars...When scrolling*.

As I recall, this is the default when installing Mountain Lion. When I first upgraded, I switched to showing scroll bars always, to avoid obscuring the content of a scrolling area. I would probably rather test in a virtual machine than change my OS settings.